# In AmE, which term is used for a student who studies a lot?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

Grind / Nerd / Bookworm / Swot
Which one of the following words describes a student who studies a lot in American English?
I think the first two choices sound natural.

Comment: @cVplZ is it necessary? Could you please let me know that why should I do that? :)

Comment: @cVplZ thank you very much for information; I know these all already, but telling the truth, I have always accepted and signed the questions which I found them informative and helpful. Otherwise I never accepted any response. However, I will review them at the earliest convenience. :)

Answer (score 2):

*Grind* could work but sounds rather old-fashioned.

*Nerd* has acquired many subtle connotations beyond studiousness.  Currently I think of it as describing someone with a strong or perhaps excessive interest in understanding or analyzing something, but it doesn't have to be school: one can be a computer nerd, or a Harry Potter nerd, or a Stack Exchange nerd.  (Indeed, some of these things might actually be harmful to a person's studying.)  It also can imply a corresponding lack of social skills.  When used in reference to one's self, it can be a term of pride or mild self-deprecation; when used about other people it's often pejorative.

*Bookworm* certainly refers to someone who spends a lot of time reading books, but that's not the same as studying; they might read books unrelated to school.

*Swot* is specific to British English and is not used in AmE.

Answer (score 1):

Other than *swot*, all are used in both AmE and BrE. *Swot* is in BrE as stated on WordWeb.

> [swot (n - Usage Brit)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=swot) - *An insignificant student who is ridiculed as being affected or boringly studious.*

If you see there, on the same page,  **grind, nerd, and wonk** are used in North America. However, **please note** that not **all** terms mean a studious person. Ah, I just said it! If you want to be neutral and stay clear for the term and **only** concerned with *a lot of studies*, **[studious](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/studious)**  looks preferred choice to me though it's plain and simple.

Comment: Yea, I know it already Maulik. It was very simple to realize this fact that "studious" is the most applicable word (if I was going to add it to my offered list), but here I was going to discover some slight nuances among my suggested words. Anyway thank you for your attention. ;)

Comment: @A-friend Aw! If you want to know the nuances, any dictionary is sufficient to tell you so! I drew your attention that if you are speaking about *studying a lot* as in your heading, those words **may** not be suitable at all! Because, most of them, I guess, involve boredom and that may tarnish a studious person's image. Ha ha!

Answer (score 0):

Nerd and bookworm are certainly more common words for me, but I speak proper, er, I mean, British English.

Answer (score 0):

"Bookworm" is a quaint and extremely mild, old-fashioned epithet for someone who is always reading. "Nerd" is a little meaner, and also a little more childish (for example, it wouldn't be insulting, when talking to another parent, to remark that their child is more of a bookworm than yours, but it would be insulting to remark that their child is more of a nerd). I have never heard the other two, but I haven't been in school for a while.

Comment: Thanks Hunter, but Which would sound the most usable with a derogatory intonation. the meaning which is in my mind contains some negative connotation. We know it well that studying a lot is a way to gain success for a student and can cause a brilliant future fir them. Of course this is a traditional advice from parents to their children, but sometimes studying a lot can be considered something not pleasant for the other class mates in schools and even in higher educational degrees. (Maybe because of jealousy or so on) So there should be a word in AE applicable to a student of this type.

Answer (score -2):

The terms you indicated have acquired other meanings. For example:

- [nerd](http://www.indeed.com/salary/Virtual-Nerd.html) - Someone who earns about $80k starting salary after college.  Some can make this after high-school.

These are the most natural and useful terms to describe one who studies a lot.

- [studious](https://www.google.com/search?q=studious) - spending a lot of time studying or reading. *He is quiet and studious.*
- [scholarly](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+scholarly) - involving or relating to serious academic study.  *He is the scholarly type; I wouldn't be surprised if he gets a PhD.*

The following are the common slang terms used in American English.  Note that all slang terms may be interpreted as derogatory:

- [pointy-head](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+pointy-headed) - A very common term in AmE for someone who studies a lot.  This can be male or female.  It can also refer to a family of aliens that actually have pointy heads and live next door. *Hey pointy-head where are you going?  The library? Ha ha!*
- [bluestocking](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS550US550&es_sm=93&q=define+bluestocking&oq=define+bluestocking&gs_l=serp.3..0.2677.4243.0.4616.7.7.0.0.0.0.321.783.5j1j0j1.7.0.ckp%2Ckpns%3D1000...0...1.1.40.serp..2.5.582.8AbbIrUU530) - This can refer to intellectual women in particular.  *Hey bluestocking where are you going?  The library? Ha ha!*

Comment: Thank you CoolHandLouis
But could you possibly let me know whether "pointy-head" can be used by a child as a reference to another child e.g. in a school and at the same time for a university student? Does this slang meet all my descriptions since the beginning of this thread?

Comment: That's a good point.  Pointy-head is often used for new-born children that have pointy-heads. And if you want, you can suggest that pointy-head newborns will become studious. But at this point, it's really only conjecture because the studies have not yet been performed. They would need to use the scientific method with double-blind tests.

Comment: And it's a problem to test because people can see if they have pointy heads or not, so they would have to put bags over their heads and tags on the bags and bags and tags over the heads of all the control-group children. They would need to lead absolutely completely normal lives. Except for the bags that covered their heads at all times. After 22 years, the study would be over, the locks could be cut, the bags removed, and based on test scores, we would finally know for sure if pointy-heads really are pointy-heads.

Comment: I'm a native AmE speaker, and I've never in my life heard the words "pointy-head" or "bluestocking" used in such a context.  They may be used somewhere, but "common" seems like an overstatement to me.